# What I thought was a discriminated union is complaining when I try to use it

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I was creating a little type utility in Typescript to mimic **Rust**'s `Result<T,E>` type. I figured it would be pretty easy and it is largely working but I'm a bit flumexed by the error I get from this code block:

```
export const RESULT = {
  Ok: "ok",
  Err: "err"
} as const;


export type BaseErr = string | { msg: string };


export type Ok<T> = { state: typeof RESULT.Ok; val: T };
export type Err<
  E extends BaseErr
> = {  state: typeof RESULT.Err; err: E };

export type Result<
  T = unknown,
  E extends BaseErr = BaseErr
> = Ok<T> | Err<E>;


/**
 * **isOk**(result)
 * 
 * Type guard which tests whether the `Result<T,E>` is in the **Ok** state.
 */
export function isOk<
  R extends Result<T,E>,
  T,
  E extends BaseErr
>(result: R): result is Ok<T> {
  return result.state === RESULT.Ok;
}
```

- available as [an interactive TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&pretty=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wEoFEDKBVAGQBU4BeOAbwCg44B5AawC44AiCB1gGhriyigtWwAayoBfOAENUiFOgDcVZaEiw4MAJ5hgcAEIzg-KGTjooAS2QBzOAB9KcALaprLc1dvilK8NHhaOvQMADxEAHymFGYwUjDALIHAEABmcNj4xAB0jApwAG5SADYsJN5Uqv4a2rrGIbxYcKDxyAAmsgaoRgJUkeTRMXEJ1Tqp6biERFnGeSKCfHDlFX7qSenAqACuRTD1tCTkm8gMyBAA7sg8tI3NwG0dhsamnd1QvaaMYZEOdVjhPlQAPQAKmBNGBcFBFlQjFBAAooBttjAAJTguDoog1ODWTZSKCtOBnAAWFgQxI0GxgshJwBgxJEGgZcAABhgkTswlw-iy4NC+cgmbpQbCIeghllwYDlmp4CkjggYBYUHyYaFeBgmiAWu11ltOURueErnBDQ0tTqHl1jL0ERyYCwMCiWIj9fB+Z8IpReIiYJsoILXcisuL4mRSOQMpMcgwlOJlEA)

While the `Result<T,E>` type is a discriminated union between `Ok<T> | Err<E>` when I try to express that **result is Ok** in the `isOk()` type guard, it gives me the error:

> A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.

Can anyone help me over the line here?

Comment: Why did you use `R`, first of all? Why not just `isOk<T, E extends BaseErr>(result: Result<T, E>): result is Ok<T>`? What problem were you trying to solve by adding a third type parameter?

Comment: Yeah, there's no guarantee that `Ok<T>` will be assignable to `R` since `R` can be narrower than `Result<T, E>`.  I would write it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/NloK5w) as the previous comment says. If that works for you I'd be happy to write up an answer (but only if @STerliakov doesn't want to). If not, please [edit] to motivate the `R` here.

Comment: See [`@sniptt/monads`](https://github.com/sniptt-official/monads)

Comment: jcalz and Sterliakov I think was thinking that my approach might maintain more literal types but i'm not sure it does and you're both correct that Sterliakov's approach works and that's really all I need :)

Comment: @jcalz go on! I know a lot about python's type system, but you can explain TS typing caveats much better:)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with

```
function isOk<R extends Result<T,E>, T, E extends BaseErr>(
  result: R): result is Ok<T> {
  return result.state === RESULT.Ok;
}
```

is that it's got too many [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters, which gives callers more freedom than you want.

The type parameter `R` is just [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Result<T, E>`, so it might be even more specific, such as `Result<T, E> & {magic: string}`.  But then a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) `x extends Y` requires that `Y` be assignable to `typeof X`.  But `Ok<T>` is not assignable to `Result<T, E> & {magic: string}`, since `Ok<T>` has no `"magic"` property.

---

You could patch that up by assuming `R` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) and then [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) the member assignable to `Ok<T>`, which will definitely be assignable to `R`:

```
function isOk<R extends Result<T, E>, T, E extends BaseErr>(
  result: R): result is Extract<R, Ok<T>> {
  return result.state === RESULT.Ok;
}
```

but this still isn't very useful for callers since `T` and `E` serve no purpose. You'll see they always fall back to their constraints, `unknown` and `BaseErr`, respectively:

```
declare const r: Result<Date, { msg: "oops" }>;
isOk(r) 
/* function isOk<Result<Date, { msg: "oops"; }>, unknown, BaseErr>(
     result: Result<Date, { msg: "oops"; }>
   ): result is Ok<Date> */
```

So they can be removed:

```
function isOk<R extends Result>(
  result: R): result is Extract<R, Ok<unknown>> {
  return result.state === RESULT.Ok;
}
isOk(r)
/* function isOk<Result<Date, { msg: "oops";}>>(
     result: Result<Date, { msg: "oops"; }>
   ): result is Ok<Date> */
```

and now the function is generic in just a single type parameter, and it still works.

---

Or, you could fix it by removing `R` instead, and let the function be generic in just `T` and `E`, so there's no possibility that `result` will be of type *narrower* than `Result<T, E>`:

```
function isOk<T, E extends BaseErr>(
  result: Result<T, E>): result is Ok<T> {
  return result.state === RESULT.Ok;
}
isOk(r)
/* function isOk<Date, { msg: "oops"; }>(
     result: Result<Date, { msg: "oops"; }>
   ): result is Ok<Date> */
```

But again, `E` isn't doing any heavy lifting here, it can be replaced with its constraint and still work:

```
function isOk<T>(
  result: Result<T, BaseErr>): result is Ok<T> {
  return result.state === RESULT.Ok;
}
isOk(r)
/* function isOk<Date>(
     result: Result<Date, BaseErr>
   ): result is Ok<Date> */
```

Personally I find this last version to be the best, since it's so simple. The one type parameter corresponds directly to the type argument of `Ok<>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&pretty=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wEoFEDKBVAGQBU4BeOAbwCg44B5AawC44AiCB1gGhriyigtWwAayoBfOAENUiFOgDcVZaEiw4MAJ5hgcAEIzg-KGTjooAS2QBzOAB9KcALaprLc1dvilK8NHhaOvQMADxEAHymFGYwUjDALIHAEABmcNj4xAB0jApwAG5SADYsJN5Uqv4a2rrGIbxYcKDxyAAmsgaoRgJUkeTR6HEJ1Tqp6biERFnGeSKCfHDlFX7qSenAqACuRTD1tCTkm8gMyBAA7sg8tI3NwG0dhsamnd1QvaaMYZEOdVjhPlQUkcEDALCg4BZUIwAIwhDBNEAtdrrLY7MJcPjhDFEDE3RF3ZEvYzhAAUvCgG22MBYGAAlCwKaj4JC+IioFIQXCMZ8IpFqLQKTBNlBkHBGVSsoN4mRSOQMpMcgwlOJlK1gAgilIKXI0PB5hhKWiACJDDHRFxuNgQCBgVCsRb-KiQmEkqC0qgAegAVHAgcgQWDRc6GLCDUyQib4mbnK4hNbbaw8uIsXAjidzpd9I8BKTeLQxYbqSiqRHTY4LXGbXak+E8-SC0yIbJPpHgJEvR7lIDgaDwcGAExwhFI2Rhqm5gWFmn18U7JusmDszkYbmhNOnC7hPnk4BCkUNiVS3SyuUTbK5CROqEMfuu93e309wNNxiDsfGsvm2NWquJ5MT-MDx2GlC1LKNy2-dhfxrOsGULecWyGdtO2UP0Az7a8AGZ0QWW57izLpiTJScmRA8McUxGd4JZHlt0nPdRVnGBJViaUT3GTIpgvFVg0wu9PR9NDeyDLCwOAaMKx-BMa2IwCmLIktWwkyD42rB1YKA5lm1CVtkNQp8MMYAAWL5ZPk4s0QookcyoxsaNCCJKB3BjNJYoYZVPTjFWVK9jP4h8hOfYMTN02T83M99diUgjXlrfNbKpBCdKQuAOyoIA)